# Pressed border CSS

Tags: html, css, webkit, border, pressed

Having a very simple and kinda embarrasing problem to be honest. 
I just can't seem to figure out how to achieve the border effect in the follwing picture:

http://cdn.churchm.ag/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/indented.png

I've tried so many different things, and even spent way too long, using webkit-border-image, to try an achieve the effect trough an external jpg file I had created in photoshop, LOL.

Anyways, I'm here seeking for guidance, all I need is the snippet of code that will achieve top/bottom/left/right borders as in the image.

And to be even more anoying, I would kindly ask that the border would be the following basecolor: #4b5ed6.

If you don't get what I'm looking for look up: http://www.bet365.dk/
I want to create the same effect of the border as they have on the wrapper with the background color being #6779e8 and the border looking pressed as on their site.

In advance - Thank you!

Comment: right mouse click, inspect element

Comment: This likely involves a combination of a darker bottom border and lighter top border on the subsequent element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be achieved by using `<hr>`:

```html
text
<hr>
text
<hr>
text
```

Or `inset` border:

```css
.myBorder{
   border:inset 1px; 
}
```

```html
text
<div class="myBorder"></div>
text
<div class="myBorder"></div>
text
```

Note that in case with `inset` border, you can also customize its width or color:

```css
.myBorder{
   border:inset 2px; 
   border-color:green;
}
```

```html
text
<div class="myBorder"></div>
text
<div class="myBorder"></div>
text
```